# Dirichlet approximation theorem: How "sporadic" are the good denominators?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, diophantine-approximation

For an irrational number $\alpha \in \Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$, the Dirichlet approximation theorem states that there are infinitely many *irreducible* fractions $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^2}$.

I would like to know if anything is known about how "sporadic" these "good denominators" $q$ are. Specifically, I would like to know whether the following holds:

> Are there $B,C > 1$ such that for every $n \in \Bbb{N}$, there is $q \in \Bbb{N} \cap [B^n, B^{n+1}]$ and $p \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\frac{p}{q}$ is *irreducible* and $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{C}{q^2}$?

In the above question, $B,C$ are allowed to depend on $\alpha$ if need be. I would also be willing to relax the desired estimate to $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{C}{q^{2-\epsilon}}$ for arbitrary $\epsilon \in (0,2)$ and $C,B$ depending on $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$.

**Motivation**:
The idea here is that for any given $K \geq 1$, I want to be able to choose $q \sim K$ satisfying the estimate $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{C}{q^2} \sim K^{-2}$. My ultimate goal is to prove a kind of "quantitative equidistribution theorem", i.e., I want to estimate $\sup_{f \in \mathcal{F}} \big|\frac{1}{N} \sum_{\ell=1}^N f(\alpha \ell) - \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \big| \lesssim N^{-\beta}$ for a certain class of periodic functions $\mathcal{F}$, and the above estimate would be a big help for doing so.

Disclaimer: I have next to no knowledge about number theory, so it might be that my question is somewhat stupid. In any case I am looking forward to learning something.

Comment: Just a question. Wouldn't denominators with a pattern of $n!$ be considered a good denominator?

Comment: @Jaden: At least one problem of the sequence $n!$ is that they "grow too fast", and thus are "too sporadic". In particular, no matter how you pick $B$, you will always have $[B^m, B^{m+1}] \cap \{ n! \,\,\colon\,\, n \in \Bbb{N} \} = \varnothing$ for infinitely many $m \in \Bbb{N}$. To see this, note that $(n+1)! / n! = n+1 \to \infty$.

Comment: Are you looking for results that hold for all $\alpha$ or almost all $\alpha$?

Comment: @user760870: If possible, I would like it to hold for all irrational $\alpha$. But almost all would still be much better than nothing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical remark to start: the interval $[X,B^2 X]$ contains two powers of $B$, so one can replace the assumption that the integer $q \in [B^m,B^{m+1}]$ by the weaker condition that for any $X$ there is a $q \in [X,B^2 X]$ satisfying the conditions.

Let's start with the bad news; certainly some $\alpha$ **do not** have any such approximation, note even the weaker bound:

$$\left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^{1 + \epsilon}}$$

for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$. To see this, let

$$\alpha = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^{m!}}$$

This is Liouville number (transcendental) which has extremely good rational
approximations. For example, we can let

$$\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{10^{m!}}$$

and then

$$\left| \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| \le \frac{2}{q^{n+1}_n} = \frac{2}{q_{n+1}}.$$

The key point, however, is that very good approximations tend to repell other good approximations. The triangle inequality says that

$$\left| \frac{p}{q} - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|
\le \left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| +
\left| \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right| \le \frac{1}{q^{1 + \epsilon}}
+ \frac{2}{q_{n+1}}.$$

Now choose $X$ such that:

$$3 \cdot 10^{n!/\epsilon} < X < B^2 X < 10^{(n+1)!/(1 + \epsilon)},$$

As long as $\epsilon > 0$, this is possible to do for $n$ large enough.
Now if $q \in  [X,B^2 X]$ then $q^{1 + \epsilon} < q_{n+1}$, so the error term
above is at must $3/q^{1 + \epsilon}$. But then we have:

$$\frac{3}{q^{1 + \epsilon}} \ge \left| \frac{p}{q} - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \right|
\ge \frac{1}{q_n q},$$

the last inequality following from using a common denominator and assuming $p/q \ne p_n/q_n$. 
But this gives:

$$q^{\epsilon} < 3q_n,$$

which is a contradition. The same argument more or less should even work with inequalities of the form

$$\left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| \le \frac{1}{q f(q)}$$

for any monotonically increasing function $f(q) \rightarrow \infty$, after replacing $\alpha$ by
another Liouville number with even more drastic convergents.

Now the second bad news. Suppose instead of $p/q$ such that:

$$\left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^2},$$

for all $\alpha$, you only ask about it for almost all $\alpha$. Here I am particular in making the RHS of the form $1/q^2$. Even this is too much to ask.
It turns out that the inequality above implies that $p/q$ is a  convergent to $\alpha$. But the denominators $q_n$ of the convergent turn out to grow exponentially, and given the continued fraction $\alpha = [a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3, \ldots]$ there's a formula:
$$q_n = a_{n} q_{n-1} + q_{n-2} \in [a_n q_{n-1},(a_n + 1) q_{n-1}].$$
Hence requiring that there is a $q \in [B^m,B^{m+1}]$ is would imply that the integers $a_i$ bounded. But it turns out that almost all real numbers have unbounded $a_i$ (by the Gauss-Kuzmin Theorem).

The continued fraction at least tells you roughly what to expect -- by Khinchin's theorem the geometric mean of the $a_n$ converge (almost always) to a fixed constant $K$, which implies that (a.a.) the $q_n$ also grow at most exponentially, which implies that you can  find a $B$ such that the desired approximation holds for $q \in [B^n,B^{n+1}]$ for "many" $n$. You could also consider the relaxed inequality with $1/q^{2 - \epsilon}$ and then think about what happens for almost all $\alpha$, although I haven't thought much about that.

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful. I think I need to refresh my memory on continued fractions. Maybe I will then come back with more questions :) Once it is possible (in like 11 hours), I will award you a bounty! One detail: Whenever you write "partial fraction", I guess you mean "continued fraction", or maybe "truncated continued fraction"?

Comment: I meant to refer to the truncated continued fractions $p_n/q_n$, I'm not sure of the exact notation for what $p_n/q_n$ or $a_n$ are called (so made light edit to remove that misleading usage).